# Spring Security FilterChain Not getting executed in Order

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, security, spring-security

Requirements:
user will be able to login to the system through two different login urls

1. admin users will login -> /admin_login
2. guest users will login -> /guset_login
   different authentication source for both the users

question:
when login through admin user, able to see all the admin pages and everything working fine
but trying to access guest user pages giving 404(not found) error, it should redirect to guest user login page

same when login through guest user , able to see all the pages accessible to guest user, but while accessing admin user pages it giving 404 error. it should redirect to admin login page

SecurityConfigone Class:

```
package com.securityexample;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.securityexample.providers.GuestAuthenticationProvider;
import com.securityexample.providers.MyCustomAuthenticationProvider;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfigOrder1 {

    @Autowired
    MyCustomAuthenticationProvider myCustomeAuthenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChainApp1(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authenticationProvider(myCustomeAuthenticationProvider);

        http.antMatcher("/admin/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAuthority("ADMIN").and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/admin_login").loginProcessingUrl("/admin/process-login")
                .failureUrl("/admin_login?error=error").defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/page1").usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password").and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/admin_login?logout=true").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied").and().csrf().disable();

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

SecurityConfigClass2

```
package com.securityexample;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.securityexample.providers.GuestAuthenticationProvider;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(2)
public class SecurityConfigOrder2 {
    @Autowired
    GuestAuthenticationProvider guestAuthenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChaninApp2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authenticationProvider(guestAuthenticationProvider);

        http.antMatcher("/guest/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAuthority("GUEST_USER").and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/guest_login").loginProcessingUrl("/guest/process-login")
                .failureUrl("/guest_login?error=error").defaultSuccessUrl("/guest/page1").usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("otp").and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/guest/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/guest_login?logout=true").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied").and().csrf().disable();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

please need help, if anybody could help ?

getting error while accessing guest user pages if login as admin user
and vice versa.

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Dec 27 22:26:41 IST 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```